# Downscale BitmapImage according to the label's width

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I would like my `BitmapImage` to scale according to the width of `Label`.
Here is a very simple piece of code:

```
<s:VGroup>
    <s:BitmapImage width="100%" source="@Embed('/image.png')" fillMode="scale" scaleMode="stretch"/>
    <s:Label text="Short"/>
</s:VGroup>
<s:VGroup>
    <s:BitmapImage width="100%" source="@Embed('/image.png')" fillMode="scale" scaleMode="stretch"/>
    <s:Label text="Very long message"/>
</s:VGroup>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

As you can see, my image is upscaling willingly, while it doesn't downscale at all.

What's the reason behind it? Is there an easy solution?

Note: it is not an option for me to set the width of `BitmapImage` to the width of `Label`.

Comment: How big is the actual image? The BitmapImage component might not scale it to a size below the actual size. Also make sure that the minWidth property is not causing the problem by setting it to a very small value.

Comment: The image is as large as it is in the case of "Short". You are right, it doesn't scale below the actual size, but why? If I explicitly set its width to the width of label, it will downscale. Though, as I've said, it is not an option for me.

Comment: width="100%" says - get as big as me... or the biggest thing in my container.  If you want it to fit the label.. tell it width="{label.width}".. EDIT... <s:Label id="myLabel" text="blah"/>   then set width="{myLabel.width}"

Comment: Jason has the right answer. It should be noted that when you give something a percent width/height, the Flex layouts will never make that object smaller than it's measuredMinWidth (or height). In this case, the image's min width is the calculated as the actual width of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pasted my comment as answer for this.

width="100%" says - get as big as me... or the biggest thing in my container. If you want it to fit the label.. tell it width="{label.width}".. EDIT...  then set width="{myLabel.width}"